# Rectangle with only outline and no fill gm nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

I am trying to draw a rectangle on top of an image using below code to have nothing filled in the rectangle. That is transparent and only outline of rectangle. But I am not able to do it. Is there a way to achieve that? Thanks.

```
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
var picGm = gm(inputFile)
picGm.drawRectangle(589, 424, 620, 463)
```

I tried below but it made the rectangle disappear.

```
picGm.fill("none").drawRectangle(589, 424, 620, 463)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution

```
picGm.stroke("#FFFFFF", 0).fill("rgba( 255, 255, 255 , 0 )").drawRectangle(589, 424, 620, 463)
```

Comment: For me you code draws white rectangles, NOT transparent. Any idea?

Comment: It is working for me now as well. It is giving transparent rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

`pic.stroke("Red", 0).fill("None")`